# Find the owner of the max value in Java

Tags: java

Trying some java code and I would like to find the dog with the most favorite things. Essentially, a comparison of the favThings value for each Dog. I tried the following but didn't work.
Furthermore if you can share some advice to keep in mind regarding the following, it will be awesome since I am new in Java.

```
public class Dog {
    String breed;
    boolean hasOwner;
    int age;
    int favThings;
    public Dog(String dogBreed, boolean dogOwned, int dogYears, int things) {
        breed = dogBreed;
        hasOwner = dogOwned;
        age = dogYears;
        favThings = things;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog fido = new Dog("poodle", false, 4, 31);
        Dog nunzio = new Dog("shiba inu", true, 12, 3);
        Dog las = new Dog("Collie", true, 5, 4);
        System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is " + max(Dog.favThings));
    }
}
```

The problem is in the last line. In order to get th ename of the dog with the most favorite things I wrote: `max(Dog.favThings)` which is not what is needed.

What it returns is:

```
Dog.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is "+ max(Dog.favThings));
                                                               ^
  symbol:   method max(int)
  location: class Dog
2 errors
```

Comment: What does "It didn't work" mean?

Comment: Hi, can you please show us what you tried so far?

Comment: It would be easier if you added your objects to a collection

Comment: @JoakimDanielson easier to do what? We don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @nicomp I know because I read the code. Also, don't you think it is easier to find the max value from a collection than a bunch of separate objects?

Comment: @nicomp Yeah it is actually pretty clear to me what he is doing wrong, he thinks he can just find the max out of all the dogs `favThings`  without using a collection or actually comparing them to each other.  I agree with Joakim

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You can't determine what someone is trying to do by reading their code.   /s

Comment: @nicomp actually quite a few of us did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have to put all `Dog` instances in a list and then use the stream `max(..)` method that allows to specify a custom comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog fido = new Dog("poodle", false, 4, 31);
    Dog nunzio = new Dog("shiba inu", true, 12, 3);
    Dog las = new Dog("Collie", true, 5, 4);

    List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(fido);
    list.add(nunzio);
    list.add(las);

    // We use a custom comparator that compares two Dog instances 'a' and 'b' based on the favThings field:
    Dog maxDog = Collections.max(list, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.favThings, b.favThings));

    System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is " + maxDog.breed);
}
```

Comment: I don't think streams are the best solution here. You end up with this annoying call to 
`Optional::get` which your IDE will warn you about not checking. It's annoying to suppress it, and verbose to work around it properly. `Collections.max` does the job just as well.

Comment: it returns: Multiple markers at this line
 - ArrayList cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - List cannot be resolved to a 
  type

Comment: @Michael You are right about `Collections.max`, I updated that. However in your version the `Comparator.comparing` is IMHO a bit hard to understand for a newbie.

Comment: @user12176582 Use on IDE that helps you importing the correct classes. Nearly every IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, ...) does this for you. See also https://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html

Comment: I have added the libraries and now it says: The type com.sun.tools.javac.util.List is not accessible

Comment: @user12176582 That is the wrong class. `List` is in 99.9999% of all occurrences `java.util.List`. Just as a small reminder: Never use classes from within the `com.sun` package. I think you should really starting with a Java tutorial that explains the basics (classes) of Java.

Comment: I am doing a basics right now.Tried to do that max attempt on my own but it appears it wasn't as simple as expected. The library I described was imported on its own after doing the ctrl shift +o

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a collection so that you can iterate/loop through all of the dogs: an array, a set, a list, etc.

```
List<Dog> allDogs = Arrays.asList(fido, nunzio, las);
```

You can then use a method such as `Collections.max`, specifying a "comparator" - a method to be used to determine the order.

```
Dog mostFavs = Collections.max(allDogs, Comparator.comparing(dog -> dog.favThings));
```

E.g.

```
List<Dog> allDogs = Arrays.asList(fido, nunzio, las);
Dog mostFavs = Collections.max(allDogs, Comparator.comparing(dog -> dog.favThings));
System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is " + mostFavs);
```

You will need a `toString` method for `Dog`, or your output will be something like

> The dog with the most fav things is **Dog@58d25a40**

Or do something like

```
System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is a " + mostFavs.breed);
```

which will give you

> The dog with the most fav things is a poodle

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you store your `Dog`s in an array or a list to make this easier:

```
Dog[] dogs = new Dog[3];
dogs[0] = new Dog("poodle", false, 4, 31);
dogs[1] = new Dog("shiba inu", true, 12, 3);
dogs[2] = new Dog("Collie", true, 5, 4);
```

At this point its just the standard algorithm to find the max value:

```
Dog dogWithMax = null;
for(Dog dog: dogs) {
    if(dogWithMax == null || dog.favThings > dog.favThings) {
        dogWithMax = dog; //we found a bigger one
    }
}
System.out.println("The dog with max favThings is: " + dogWithMax.toString());
```

The `toString` method can, for example, can create a string from the dogs attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know the number of favorite things of the dog, you must access the object created by you (fido, nunzio, las) and retrieve the `favThings` attribute.

Example: `fido.favThings;`

If you want to find out which dog has the most favorite things, I recommend you create a list of dogs and look for the dog with the most favorite things.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Main method started");
    Dog fido = new Dog("poodle", false, 4,31); 
    Dog nunzio = new Dog("shiba inu", true, 12,3);
    Dog las = new Dog("Collie",true, 5,4);

    // Step 1: Put all of the dogs into a list so we can compare all dogs easily
    Collection<Dog> dogs = Arrays.asList(fido, nunzio, las);

    // Step 2: use the stream() and max() methods with a compare function (you could easily get the oldest dog for example by changing the Dog::getFavThings to Dog::getAge - Just add a getter to the dog class if you want to - left the extra getters out for brevity)
    Dog dogWithMostFavorites = dogs.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Dog::getFavThings)).get();

    System.out.println(dogWithMostFavorites.getBreed());
  }
}

class Dog {
  String breed;
  boolean hasOwner;
  int age;
  int favThings;

  public Dog(String dogBreed, boolean dogOwned, int dogYears,int things) {
    breed = dogBreed;  
    hasOwner = dogOwned;            
    age = dogYears;
    favThings = things;
  }

  // Added getters for testing and printing
  public Integer getFavThings() {
    return this.favThings;
  }

  public String getBreed() {
    return this.breed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a toString() method in Dog class so you can see which dog is found with the max Favorite things.

Then add each dog in a List and finally iterate the list and store the dog with the max favorite things in a variable.

When the loop finish, the dog in that variable is what you want.

```
public class Main {
public class Dog {
    String breed;
    boolean hasOwner;
    int age;
    int favThings;
    public Dog(String dogBreed, boolean dogOwned, int dogYears, int things) {
        breed = dogBreed;
        hasOwner = dogOwned;
        age = dogYears;
        favThings = things;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog{" +
                "breed='" + breed + '\'' +
                ", hasOwner=" + hasOwner +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", favThings=" + favThings +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
    //add the dogs into the list
    m.addDogs(dogList);
    System.out.println("The dog with the most fav things is " + max(dogList).toString());
}

private void addDogs(List<Dog> dogList){
    dogList.add(new Dog("poodle", false, 4, 31));
    dogList.add(new Dog("shiba inu", true, 12, 3));
    dogList.add(new Dog("Collie", true, 5, 4));
}

private static Dog max(List<Dog> dogList){
    if (dogList==null || dogList.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    //set the dog with the max favorite things as the first of the list
    Dog maxFavThings = dogList.get(0);
    for (Dog dog:dogList){
        if(maxFavThings.favThings < dog.favThings){
            //found a dog with more favorite things
            maxFavThings = dog;
        }
    }
    return maxFavThings;
}}
```

Above code will output:

> The dog with the most fav things is Dog{breed='poodle', hasOwner=false, age=4, favThings=31}